# TensorFlow control_dependencies throw Frame error when used in while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

this problem is originally posted at the [TensorFlow issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6087). Now Move to StackOverflow to see if there is some way to get around this issue : )

#### Problem description

I need to put InceptionV3 in a while loop to save both GPU and CPU memory usage since I am handling videos, each contains hundreds of images. The problem is, InceptionV3 uses `control_dependencies` for BatchNorm and TensorFlow throws Frame Error if `control_dependencies` function is in the `while_loop`. It can run without errors if `control_dependencies` is removed though.

Below is a minimal snippet that reproduces the error:

```
sess = tf.Session()

with tf.variable_scope('state'):
    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=(), 
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1), 
                             dtype=tf.float32)
    update_x = tf.assign(x, x+1)

def iter_fun(i, y):
    # comment the line below, the program will run without any error
    # but I need control_dependencies, or at least some way to replace it...
    with tf.control_dependencies([update_x]): 
        y = y + x
    return (i+1, y)

with tf.variable_scope('iteration'):
    num_iterations = 5   
    initial_i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
    initial_y = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
    _, result = tf.while_loop(
        cond=lambda i, *_: i < num_iterations,
        body=iter_fun,
        loop_vars=(initial_i, initial_y))

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)
sess.run(result)
```

The stack trace of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 28, in <module>
    sess.run(result)
  File "/workspace/bily/anoaconda2/envs/tensorflow0.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/workspace/bily/anoaconda2/envs/tensorflow0.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/workspace/bily/anoaconda2/envs/tensorflow0.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/workspace/bily/anoaconda2/envs/tensorflow0.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: The node 'iteration/while/add' has inputs from different frames. The input 'iteration/while/add/Enter' is in frame 'iteration/while/iteration/while/'. The input 'state/Assign' is in frame ''.
```

#### Environments

- CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511
- TensorFlow 0.12 built from source
- Python 2.7.12
- CUDA 7.5 and CUDNN v5.1

#### Related issues

1. [This issue in tflearn](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/427) seems to be related to my problem but removing control_denpendencies isn't a solution for me.
2. [#4478](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4478) and [#3114](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3114) are issues about frame errors but these errors are caused by variables instead of control_dependencies.

Any help will be appreciated : )

Answer (score 0):

As I replied to the github issue, a fix should show up in open source in a couple of days.

Comment: May I ask what is the status now?